# RC4 Drop-N PHP Implementation

Tags: php, encryption, rc4-cipher

I have an implementation of the RC4 cipher in PHP already (it looks almost indentical to this http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_RC42).

However, I'd like to introduce the "Drop-N" approach as mentioned in (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Fluhrer.2C_Mantin_and_Shamir_attack).

Is there a simple way to implement this based on the Class i'm using above?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add *n* bytes of data to the start of your plaintext (or ciphertext) before encrypting (or decrypting).

It doesn't matter what these bytes contain, as long as there are *n* of them. Then discard the first *n* bytes of the encrypted (decrypted) data. Using different pad bytes for encryption and decryption will make no difference.

Or in other words:

```
$define('DROP_N_PADDING_LENGTH',512);  // (or whatever)
$message = "Hello, world!";

// encrypt:
$ciphertext = $rc4->encrypt(str_repeat(" ",DROP_N_PADDING_LENGTH) . $message);
$ciphertext = substr($ciphertext,DROP_N_PADDING_LENGTH);

// decrypt:
$plaintext = $rc4->decrypt(str_repeat(" ",DROP_N_PADDING_LENGTH) . $ciphertext);
$plaintext = substr($plaintext,DROP_N_PADDING_LENGTH);
```